# Query regarding Org browser

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, vs-code

I forgetfully hide the org browser(cloud logo) in vs code. Anyone knows how to unhide it?

Answer (score 3):

Click with the right mouse button on the [Activity Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/activity-bar) then click on "Org Browser"

[image: Activity Bar]